# Откуда происходит слово "халатность"?

Tags: этимология

Где-то читал, что слово происходит от среднеазиатских "товарищей".

Answer (score 1):

Существительное ***халатность*** происходит от прилагательного ***халатный***, далее из сущ. ***халат***, из тур. ***ẋilat*** «кафтан» из араб. ***ḫil᾽аt*** «почетное платье». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Об истории употреблении слова **халатность** в русском языке — здесь:

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/280/%D0%A5%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%AC